# json_encode does not print the array name

Tags: php, datatables, json

I'm not experienced with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and am trying to return an arrray of array which should be called **aaData** - for [DataTables with server-side processing](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side).

The output should be like:

```
{
    "sEcho": 3,
    "iTotalRecords": 57,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 57,
    "aaData": [
        [
            "Gecko",
            "Firefox 1.0",
            "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
            "1.7",
            "A"
        ],
        [
            "Gecko",
            "Firefox 1.5",
            "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
            "1.8",
            "A"
        ],
        ...
    ] 
}
```

but the actuall output of my PostgreSQL 8.4-driven PHP-script

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['json'])) {
    $aaData = array();
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        array_push($aaData, $row);
    }
    print json_encode($aaData);
}
```

is actually missing outside brackets (object like?) and the **aaData** name:

```
[
    [ .... ],
    [ .... ],
    [ .... ]
]
```

How would you do this best?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to have `aaData` as the name, then you'll need to give your array an associative index, like so:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['json'])) { 
    $arr['aaData'] = array(); 
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) { 
        array_push($arr['aaData'], $row); 
    } 
    print json_encode($arr); 
}
```

Comment: That gives me {"aaData":null}

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use the code in the question but change one line:

```
print json_encode(array('aaData' => $aaData));
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain the root of your problem: The name of the variable, `$aaData`, has nothing to do with the data itself. Thus, `json_encode` does not serialize it.